# Points on a $m\cdot n$ grid with no right triangles formed

Tags: combinatorics, pigeonhole-principle

In an $m \cdot n$ rectangular grid of points, $k$ points are marked, such that no three marked points form a right triangle with legs parallel to the sides of the rectangular grid. What is the expression for the value of $k$ in relation to $m$ and $n$?

I've worked out that it is possible to create an arrangement with $m+n-2$ points, but how do I prove that given $m+n-1$ points, at least one right triangle is formed. Should I use pigeonhole principle, and how would I do so?

Comment: In your initial question you did not say you were looking for the max k given m and n. In your "worked out" section that's what you want it seems.

Comment: What is your arrangement with $m+n-2$ points? Including it would show some work, making it less likely question gets closed.

Comment: Note: $m+n-2$ doesn't give the right (maximal $k$) answer for small grids, like $1 \times 1$ or $1 \times 2$ grids.

Comment: **Hint:** Call a point _column-lonely_ if it is the only point in it column, and _row-lonely_ analogously. What is the maximum number of row-lonely points, when $m+n-1$ points are placed in the grid? What is the maximum number of column-lonely points? Putting those two answers together, can it be the case that **every** point is lonely w/ respect to some axis?

Comment: Are you referring that a point, if not row-lonely, must be column-lonely, and vice versa? Given m+n-1 points, the maximum number of row-lonely points with n rows is dependent on m?